# Road coordinates data (Cardiff)

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinates, road

Does anyone know how to get road coordinates data from OpenStreetMaps?

I know its possible I just don't know how.

Comment: Cardiff Wales, UK? or Cardiff, Alberta, Canada?

Comment: Try this new service - http://www.osm974.re/osm2gis/ Zoom in and at a correct zoom level you will be able to download in Shape,TAB,KML format the area of interest - an email is sent when the data is processed. (though check your junk/spam folder)

Answer (score 2):

You can download files for Wales here
http://download.geofabrik.de/openstreetmap/europe/great_britain/

You can download either xml or shape files.

After download you can load files in program like Qgis and select appropriate layers and export them to file or database of your choice.